# how to save and get selected item id list with add_meta_box

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

hi all i need create to metabox in page for the footer and header posttypes i created, in this code i tried for this but i cant save selected item and retrive id selected item in the frontend.

```
function wpdocs_register_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'meta-box-id', __( 'header', 'textdomain' ),'wpdocs_my_display_callback', 'page', 'normal' , 'high');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpdocs_register_meta_boxes' );
 

function wpdocs_my_display_callback() {

    ?>

    <select name="count" id="selectId" >
    <?php  

    $posts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'header')); 
    while($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
       <option id="selection" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></option>
    <?php endwhile;
    die()
    ?>
    </select>
   <?php 
}
 

function wpdocs_save_meta_box( $post_id ) {


    if (isset($_POST['selectId'])) {

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'selectId', $_POST['selectId']);
    }


}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpdocs_save_meta_box' );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use by postId like below
echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'selectId', true ) );

Answer (score 0):

Change your `wpdocs_my_display_callback` function like below.

```
function wpdocs_my_display_callback( $post ) {

    $selectId = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'selectId', true );

    ?>

    <select name="selectId" id="selectId" >
    <?php  

    $posts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'header')); 
    while($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
       <option id="selection" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" <?php selected( $selectId, get_the_ID() ); ?>><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></option>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();    
    ?>
    </select>
   <?php 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answer and that work, But in need two metabox one for header select and one for select footer. I use this code for but not work, when comment and disable section this code for header, footer is work and save. when comment footer section code, header is work and save options seleceted!!!

```
function header_register_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'meta-box-header', __( 'header', 'poedit' ),'header_my_display_callback', array('page','post'), 'side' , 'high');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'header_register_meta_boxes' );

function header_my_display_callback()
{
    global $post;
    $header_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'selected_header', true);
?>
    <select name="selected_header" id="selected_header">
        <?php
        $posts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1,'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'header'));
        echo'<option value="0">select header</option>';
        while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
            <option <?php selected($header_value, get_the_ID()); ?> id="selection_header" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></option>
        <?php endwhile;
         wp_reset_query(); 
        
        ?>
    </select>
<?php
}

function header_save_meta_box( $post_id ) {
    if (isset($_POST['selected_header'])) {

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'selected_header', $_POST['selected_header']);
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'header_save_meta_box' );




function footer_register_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'meta-box-footer', __( 'footer', 'poedit' ),'footer_my_display_callback', array('page','post'), 'side' , 'high');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'footer_register_meta_boxes' );


function footer_my_display_callback()
{
    global $post;
    $footer_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'selected_footer', true);
?>
    <select name="selected_footer" id="selected_footer">
        <?php
        $posts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1,'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'footer'));
        echo'<option value="0">select footer</option>';
        while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
        
            <option <?php selected($footer_value, get_the_ID()); ?> id="selection_footer" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></option>
        <?php endwhile;
         wp_reset_query(); 
        
        ?>
    </select>
<?php
}

function footer_save_meta_box( $post_id ) {
    if (isset($_POST['selected_footer'])) {

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'selected_footer', $_POST['selected_footer']);
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'footer_save_meta_box' );
```